# Posting MultipartFormDataContent request with HttpClient gets Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient

I send HTTP request with the `MultipartFormDataContent` but I'm getting the following error when the file size is more than 2mb:

> Error while copying content to a stream.
> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

But exactly the same request with more than 5mb file can be sent with PostMan successfully.

This is my code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(GetHttpClientHandler(requestUrl)))
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            var fileName = $"file {(i + 1)}.png";
            ByteArrayContent bContent = new ByteArrayContent(images[i]);
            content.Add(bContent, "file", fileName);
        }

        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content)) //Exception occurs here
        {
            resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        
    }
}
```

So, if the problem about the server-side why it works with PostMan? If the problem is in my code, what is that then? I think I did everything by convention.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the [recommended way of using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)!

First create custom client servis with the required upload method:

```cs
public class MyClientService : IMyClientService
{
    private readonly HttpCLient _client;

    public MyClientService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }


    public async Task<bool> UploadFilesAsync(MultipartFormDataContent content, string requestUrl)
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then register the custom client service in startup:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClientService, MyClientService>();
```

Then inject your service to the controller/page model:

```cs
private readonly IMyClientService_client;

public UploadPage(IMyClientService client)
{
    _client = client;
}
```

And use it to upload files:

```cs
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
    {
        var fileName = $"file {(i + 1)}.png";
        ByteArrayContent bContent = new ByteArrayContent(images[i]);
        content.Add(bContent, "file", fileName);
    }

    var success = await _client.UploadFilesAsync(content, requestUrl);
}
```

Comment: But I need to add specific Credentials to HttpClientHandler in every request. Thi s is not possible with the way that you suggest.

Comment: I added my GetHttpClientHandler method to my post