# .NET 6.0 Posting MultipartFormDataContent with HttpClient result in 'Error while copying content to a stream'

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

I am trying to POST a specific file using HttpClient (.NET 6.0) and `MultipartFormDataContent`, but I keep getting the following error: `Error while copying content to a stream`

However, when uploading the file through Postman or through the server's own web portal, it was successful. Unfortunately I don't have access to the remote server to know why it is failing.

Below is the sample code with some information removed.

```
public static class Program {
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler;

    private static async Task Main() {
        httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
        };

        client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://remoteServerIpAddress/");

        var filePath = "absoluteFilePath";
        var fileBytesArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        multipartFormContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytesArray));

        // Setup headers for authorization

        // Error occurs here
        var uploadResponse = await client.PostAsync("api/upload", multipartFormContent).ConfigureAwait(true);

        Console.WriteLine(await uploadResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Here is the following stacktrace of the error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Error while copying content to a stream.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<<CopyToAsync>g__WaitAsync|56_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.<SerializeToStreamAsyncCore>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<<CopyToAsync>g__WaitAsync|56_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendRequestContentAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__62.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__62.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__83.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Program.<Main>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\UploadApplication\Program.cs:line 59

Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I've seen a similar post, but did not see any solution that would help with my situation:

[Posting MultipartFormDataContent request with HttpClient gets Error while copying content to a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445714/posting-multipartformdatacontent-request-with-httpclient-gets-error-while-copyin)

I am not sure if the problem is in my code, but any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've identified the issue, and it turns out `MultipartFormDataContent` is adding double quotes around the boundary value by default, while both the server web portal and Postman **did not**.

This is an example of what the Content-Type for `MultipartFormDataContent` would look like if inspected:

`multipart/form-data; boundary="85707dac-07d6-4978-8a35-32c09f6c5b7c"`

However, the remote server was expecting no quotes in the boundary value, like the following:

`multipart/form-data; boundary=85707dac-07d6-4978-8a35-32c09f6c5b7c`

To get around this problem, I've removed the double quotes around the boundary field with the following:

```
var contentType = multipartFormContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.First();
contentType.Value = contentType.Value.Replace("\"", String.Empty);
```

This Github issue is what got my attention into looking at the boundary value:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41237

This post is where I got the solution to remove the double quotes from the boundary:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371123

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue in a previous project.  What worked for us was to use one of the overloads of the add method that required the `name` and `fileName` parameters.

```
multipartFormContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytesArray), "name", "fileName")
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but unfortunately I got the same error

Comment: I would advise to then take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host 
Something about the IOException and SocketException are leading me to believe its a connection protocol issue.